# validate input with decimal precision and scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal, jquery-1.9

I am trying to create a javascript function which is called on `keypress` event on a `input` which does the following:

- Input should be a valid decimal with format (5,2) => (XXXXX.YY) which are variable to the function. Input is restricted if user adds any value which does not conform to the format above.
- If existing input starts with `.` append `0` to the starting automatically

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return checkDecimal(event, this, 5, 2);"  id="price2" value="27.15">
```

**Javascript**

```
function checkDecimal(evt, item, lenBeforeDecimal, lenAfterDecimal) {
    var charCode = evt.which;

    var trimmed = $(item).val().replace(/\b^0+/g, "");
    if(checkStartsWith(trimmed, '.') == true){
        trimmed = '0' + trimmed;
    }

    //Allow following keys
    //8 = Backspace, 9 = Tab
    if(charCode == 8 || charCode == 9){
        return true;
    }

    //Only a single '.' is to be allowed
    if(charCode == 46){
        var dotOccurrences = (trimmed.match(/\./g) || []).length;

        if(dotOccurrences != undefined && dotOccurrences == 1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (charCode > 31 && ((charCode < 48) || (charCode > 57))) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($(item).val() != trimmed){
        $(item).val(trimmed);}


    //Check the start and end length
    if(trimmed.indexOf('.') == -1){
        if(trimmed.length >= parseInt(lenBeforeDecimal)){
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        var inputArr = trimmed.split(".");
        if(inputArr[0].length > parseInt(lenBeforeDecimal) || inputArr[1].length >= parseInt(lenAfterDecimal)){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
function checkStartsWith(str, prefix){
    return str.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
}
```

**Issues**

- If user inputs `12345.9` and then moves the caret position after `5`, user is able to add another digit before the decimal `123456.9` which should not be allowed.
- If user inputs `1.9` and then remove `1` and add `5`, `5` is added at the end and the entered value becomes `0.95` and not `5.9`

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6yjv316/3/)

Comment: Checking keystrokes and trying to reimplement the UI is usually extremely difficult and doesn't work across browsers. Consider just checking the actual value and going from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a regular expression like:

```
/^(\d{0,5}\.\d{0,2}|\d{0,5}|\.\d{0,2})$/;
```

that allows everything up to and including your required format, but returns false if the number part is more than 5 digits or if the fraction is more than 2 digits, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="check(this.value)"><span id="er"></span>

<script>

function check(v) {
  var re = /^(\d{0,5}\.\d{0,2}|\d{0,5}|\.\d{0,2})$/;
  document.getElementById('er').innerHTML = re.test(v);
}

</script>
```

You'll need separate validation for the final value, e.g.

```
/^\d{5}\.\d{2}$/.test(value);
```

to make sure it's the required format.

I don't understand the requirement to add a leading zero to "." since the user must enter 5 leading digits anyway (unless I misunderstand the question).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was using this function across different input fields which have different requirements for precision and scale. That is why my function has these as parameters. For the "leading zero before `.`", it's because `.25` is a valid value which should be displayed as `0.25`